# How can I reinstall the OS on macbook pro?

Tags: macbook-pro, high-sierra

My macbook pro mid 2015 with high sierra installed started to behave strangely.

I can boot and login, and after less than a minute it completely freezes with the spinning wheel. Then the wheel disappears, and then the screen goes black, not the keyboard.

Tried to reinstall going to recovery mode, but it found no disk to install the system.

Tried to reset SMC but no help

Any ideas?

Comment: When you state *"found no disk to install the system."*, does this mean you could not erase the internal drive using the Disk Utility while in internet recovery mode? Or, something else?

Comment: Have you try boot in Safe Mode (push on shift key at boot)?

Comment: @DavidAnderson you are correct, no disk was found. Only some strange 2 Gb partition (my sdd is a 512 gb)

Comment: @Jean_JD yes, nothing happens. Sometimes the boot process goes until the login and then it freezes, others it would be stuck on the progress bar

Comment: Carlo: Are you sure you booted to internet recovery for High Sierra? You can get the version by entering the command `sw_vers` in a Terminal window while in internet recovery. For example, if you booted to the Yosemite version of internet recovery, then the Disk Utility would not understand APFS. (I assume you have High Sierra is installed to an APFS volume.) When are booted to High Sierra recovery mode, make sure you have selected "Show All Devices".

Comment: May be the SSD is "broken". If you have an external disk usb, you can try install the system inside from recovery mode.

Comment: Carlo: Jean_JD has a point. Try plugging in a external drive such as a flash drive. If the Disk Utility in recovery mode recognizes the external drive but not the internal drive, then probably there has been an internal hardware failure.

Comment: @DavidAnderson I plugged an external flash drive, and on recovery mode it can see it and now installing the os in it. The internal ssd does not show up. Strangely sometimes I could boot normally, so I guess either the ssd is dying or have some corrupted areas. Will diagnose once the os is installed on the flash

Comment: Installing macOS to a flash drive is probably not a good idea. From my understanding,  flash drives are not designed to take the amount of reads and writes that macOS will require. You would be better off installing High Sierra on a external HDD or SSD. For HDD, use "Mac OS Extended Journaled" and for SSD use "APFS". I have Catalina installed on a Samsung T7 external SSD for use on a 2013 iMac. This performs satisfactorily, but would not be nearly as fast as your internal SSD. (Both the 2013 iMac and 2015 MacBook Pro have 5 Gb/s USB ports.)

Answer (score 1):

May be your internal SSD is "broken".
So, from Internet Recovery Mode, you install Mac OS X on an external drive and boot from it.

You can hope to recover data on the internal SSD (the ideal being to make regular backups with Time Machine).

Then if you are lucky enough to have an unsoldered SSD, which seems to be the case with the 2015 MBP, all you have to do is replace this SSD with a new one.

The 2015 MBPs accept NVME SSDs (much cheaper than original Apple SSDs) with a specialized adapter.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a bootable flash drive installer for macOS. You can use it to either reinstall, or install a fresh copy of macOS.

The instructions to create the bootable installer can be found in the Apple support document:

- https://support.apple.com/kb/HT201372

The link to the official copy of macOS High Sierra installer can be found via the following Apple support document:

- https://support.apple.com/kb/HT211683

Comment: I am aware of it. My issue is that I dont want to lose files, and If i remember correctly there would be an option to reinstall without losing data when using the internet recovery. But with a bootable flash drive it would erase it all

Comment: Carlo: I believe you are incorrect. Using a bootable flash drive has the same options as booting from internet recovery. In other words, you should be able to reinstall without losing data. (Here, I assume both the flash drive and internet recovery are of the same version of macOS installed on the internal drive.)

Comment: I installed onto an external ssd, booted from it and everything workd perfectly. The internal ssd is not shown even with "diskutil list" in terminal. I guess the disk is gone forever.